# Debug a Bootloop?

Tags: boot-loop, debug

So I'm attempting to port a GSM ROM to CDMA, and it's in a bootloop. I'd like to know how to figure out how to see what exactly is faulting and causing it so I can go fix it.

Do note I am a novice when it comes to doing something like this, but I know my way around software and hardware. I'm just doing this as a learning experience to further my knowledge in Android OS to contribute work I may start doing in the future.

Thank you for any help that can be done.